# Angular 5: order html tags inside component

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular5

I need to order html elements inside my component, based on some input flag, like this:

if flag is true:

```
<i>...</i><span>...</span>
```

else:

```
<span>...</span><i>...</i>
```

Every tag has a lot of bindings and i think it's wrong - just create 2 templates with different orders. 
So, how can i achieve this in an angular way?

At this point I found this solution:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="invert; then templateInvert else templateRegular"></ng-container>

<ng-template #templateLabel>
  ...
</ng-template>
<ng-template #templateCheckbox>
  ...
</ng-template>

<ng-template #templateRegular>
  <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="templateCheckbox"></ng-container>
  <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="templateLabel"></ng-container>
</ng-template>
<ng-template #templateInvert>
  <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="templateLabel"></ng-container>
  <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="templateCheckbox"></ng-container>
</ng-template>
```

Now, I want to know if there is a way to do the same thing easier.

Excuse me for my English and thanks for advance.

Comment: welcome to SO, please go through https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic, https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask links. showcase what you have done so far for this issue

Answer (score 0):

do something like this:

```
<div *ngIf='yourFlag'></div>
<div *ngIf='!yourFlag'></div>
```

or like this (with default css 'display:none;'):

```
<div [class.show]='yourFlag'></div>
<div [class.show]='!yourFlag'></div>
```

Comment: Alredy did, but this way i shoud dublicate html tags with a lot of bindings and every time then i need to change template i shoud do this in 2 places. Is the DRY way exist for this?

Comment: @HouseM.D. another way - create simple component and call it with **ngIf**

Comment: Yea, it is the solution too, thanks. But i don't like it. I wanna find easier way.